# Xcodebuild: Creating .ipa using -exportarchive always fails to find provisioning profile?

Tags: ios, xcode, build, xcodebuild

Trying to create ipa from archive running the following command:

```
xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath $PWD/archive/test.xcarchive -exportOptionsPlist exportOptions.plist -exportPath $PWD/build
```

Always throws an error as follows though I have the profile installed:

```
error: exportArchive: No "iOS Ad Hoc" profiles for team 'XXXXXXXXXX' matching 'adhoc_profile' are installed.

Error Domain=IDEProfileLocatorErrorDomain Code=4 "No "iOS Ad Hoc" profiles for team 'XXXXXXXXXX' matching 'adhoc_profile' are installed." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=No "iOS Ad Hoc" profiles for team 'XXXXXXXXXX' matching 'adhoc_profile' are installed., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Install a profile (by dragging and dropping it onto Xcode's dock item) or specify a different profile in your Export Options property list.}
```

*Update*: exportOptions.plist as follow

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" 
"http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd"> 
<plist version="1.0"> <dict>    
<key>compileBitcode</key>   <true/>      
<key>method</key>   
<string>ad-hoc</string>      
<key>provisioningProfiles</key>     
<dict>       
<key>com.app.appname</key>      
<string>adhoc_profile</string>  </dict>      
<key>signingStyle</key>     
<string>manual</string>      
<key>stripSwiftSymbols</key>    
<true/>     
<key>teamID</key>    
<string>XXXXXXXXXX</string>     
<key>thinning</key>      
<string>&lt;none&gt;</string> 
</dict> 
</plist>
```

Comment: Are you sure you've created an Ad Hoc provisioning profile and not an App Store one?

Comment: Yes I am pretty sure, I am able to archive and distribute using Xcode, but doing so using xcodebuild on terminal always fails to find provisioning profile

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your `exportOptionsPlist` and also the details of your provisioning profile?

Comment: Updated the post with exportOptions.plist, let me know if there is anything else. Thanks

Comment: Everything looks alright to me. Only other thing I can think of is there may be a mismatch with how the Profile has been set up on the Developer Portal. Another thing to try would be making sure you have the up to date build tools installed.

Comment: Note that xcodebuild looks for provisioning profiles in Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/*******.mobileprovision

Answer (score 0):

Try to check provisioning profile name at developer.apple.com. Are there whitespaces in the name? If so then you should pass it to `provisioningProfiles` of export options exactly like specified there, i.e. with whitespaces in the name even if the downloaded file name of provisioning profile is without whitespaces, e.g. `adhoc_profile.mobileprovision`

[image: screenshot from developer.apple.com - generate new provisioning profile]